# Has an FPGA ever caused health issues?

Tags: fpga, asic

Considering the number of people here who work closely with always on FPGAs, ASICs etc, and how materials react to heat, etc. Are there any known health issues when dealing with 
hot electronics emitting any material that is unhealthy to breathe or be around?

Comment: I heard that cell phone users get brain tumors when they talk too much, or testicle's cancel if they keep the phone in their pocket. Never heard FPGAs causing health issues though.

Comment: Testicles only cancel if they are 180 degrees out-of-phase.

Comment: Yes. After many nights of working with them I got PTSD.

Comment: They've made me tear out my hair ;)

Comment: Perhaps [The Terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator) was implemented with an FPGA.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky Placement Trauma & Synthesis Disease? :-)

Comment: Rosin vapors are powerful anti-oxidants which protect from all the other bad stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but I'd postulate the following:

- Your biggest risk is inhalation of fumes from soldering. The materials involved (e.g. lead) are often hazardous, and flux fumes are known to cause irritation of the lungs.
- If you're directly involved in chip fabrication, silicon dust is another hazard to avoid, since it can lead to [silicosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis) if inhaled.
- Many component casings are made of polymers, which might give off some nasty gases if burned. You're probably looking at molecules containing halogens (e.g. chlorine), which may be hazardous if breathed. However, you're unlikely to release more than trace amounts of these unless you actually burn the case directly with the iron.
- Long-term exposure to smoke and other chemicals on your fingers may cause hardening and discolouration, but this is highly unlikely to be damaging to your health in general.
- An appropriate fume extractor should be enough to protect you from most problems.

All in all I don't think there are any risks that are *specific* to ASIC / FPGA handling.

Comment: BTW- in  your profile "encrypted with ROT256-ECB." ... clever though I pasted mine in Sec.SE without ever seeing yours.

Comment: If you're involved in chip fabrication, silicon dust is only a minor one of your worries. There's lots of nasty chemicals used in fabs: cyanide solutions, hydrofluoric acid, ...

Comment: @ThePhoton Sure, but in my (rather limited) experience those tend to be part of an automated process in a restricted area, where respirators and other safety equipment are mandatory and human interaction is usually not required. There tend to be less restrictions around areas that only deal with slicing silicon dies.

Comment: Also, accidentally inhaling decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @SimonRichter Particularly with [008004 capacitors](https://www.mouser.co.uk/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Ceramic-Capacitors/MLCCs-Multilayer-Ceramic-Capacitors/Multilayer-Ceramic-Capacitors-MLCC-SMD-SMT/_/N-bkrdv?P=1ynxmrs).

Comment: @makerofthings7 browse "ROT256-ECB". Too many Polynomials.

Answer (score 4):

Running electronics is not known to be harmful to health just from being near it.

Assembling electronics has various minor health hazards - inhaling burning flux can induce asthma; lead in solder has been phased out due to its toxicity.